# Book recommendation on primordial magnetogenesis

Tags: cosmology, magnetic-fields, resource-recommendations

I have a background in GR and FRW cosmology. I want to learn about primordial magnetogenesis. Could anyone suggest a book?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3891

Comment: Thanks for this.